# LESS- How to add .active to parent selector during inherency?

Tags: less

Not a LESS guy and I am assuming this is easy or not possible.  I am trying to combine these into only having li > a once and have the .active applied within it.  Similar to how you can have a &:first-child.

```
.nav {
  apply styles;

    li > a {
     apply styles;
    }

    li.active > a {
     apply styles;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```less
.nav {
  // styles
  li {
    & > a {/* styles */}
    &.active > a {/* styles */}
}
```

Comment: I think this will be the closest to what I want/can do.  I was hoping of someway to not have to repeat the > a too, but don't think it is possible.  Thanks... I was going about it wrong in my head :]